# How do i extract specific excel rows based on column data from a different excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

Just need pointed in the right direction or even told if its possible or not.

So I have two massive excel files both over 700K rows.

The goal: Find the delta

The issue: too many unique data points to find a true delta without scraping most of the content of each files down to a simple claims number then running this...

```
    import csv

fn1 = "C:/Users/****/Downloads/Files (5)/Claims_*******_20210507.txt"
fn2 = "C:/Users/*****/Downloads/Files (5)/Claims_**********_20210514.txt"

with open(fn1) as f1, open(fn2) as f2:
   header = next(f1)
   st = set(f1)
   with open("C:/Users/********/Downloads/Files (5)/out.txt", "w") as out:
       out.writelines((line for line in f2 if line not in st))
```

**** found this code from this website its a peach!****

To get the true delta...

So my question... Now that i have the delta data (claims numbers) is there a way for me to use python to pull the rest of the data associated with that column (claims number).

I would just suffer and do a vlookup on each column based against the claims number but each file is over 700k rows so putting the data together in one spreadsheet isnt happening.

Outside of opening access which i dont want to do, can someone point me in the right direction of what i need to study or learn? or share their wisdom if this is even possible? I keep seeing something for panda but nothing to my specific needs.

Comment: Do you have Excel files, or text files? Your code snippet suggests the latter.

Comment: So I get the files in .txt format that I then take into excel and then text to columns

Comment: I suggest you don't do that. Excel is not great for that much data.

Comment: Ok, what do you suggest then? I need to find the delta but because of data in the files i cannot run the above script and get a solid delta without removing all data except claim number. Once I have the claims number i technically have the delta but now I need ot get the rest of the data associated with that claims number.

Comment: Use pandas and `read_csv`, specifying the delimiter as necessary.